# How to create two columns (one with two rows and other with one) without using fixed sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've successfully created two columns with various number of rows, however, I don't want to use fixed sizes. Is it possible without Javascript?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='row'>test</div>
        <div class='row'>test</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
           test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.row
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 50%;
}
.cell
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/XyYND/22/

Comment: **a)** Why not to just use tables? **b)** css display:table **c)** if you asking how to create same-height dynamic elements, use JS **d)** Watch out your class terminology, since when are rows inside of cells?

Comment: It might be useful for you to provide a picture/sketch of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Tom on this one. Forget the "don't use tables for make up" statement.
If you're trying to create a table, use the element defined as a table in stead of giving a div all the properties of a table.

Comment: What are you intending it to be used for? As a <table> element might be completely acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add height:100% to your other elements.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/XyYND/23/

And the CSS:

```
html {
height:100%;
}

body
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height:100%;
}
.table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.row
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 50%;
}
.cell
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>
        <div class='row'>test</div>
        <div class='row'>test</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
           test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox ([**Fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfn7e4cz/1/)):

```
.table
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
.cell
{
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

`flex: 1;` will make the divs take as much space as possible.